# get host list from zabbix api with python

Tags: python, json, zabbix

Please help me, give some ideas or some code))
I have the lists all hosts, and list all keys who exist in zabbix server.
So, when i select needed key, how i can show which server have this key?
In my example, how i can take list hosts, who have key vmware? Thanks
My example:

```
data = {
                    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                    "method": "host.get",
                    "params": {
                            "output": "extend"
                    },
                    "auth": authId,
                    "id": 2
            }
            request = requests.post(path, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'content-type':'application/json-rpc'})
            result = []
            request_res = request.json()['result']
            for item in request_res:
                    result.append(item['hostid'])
            data = {
                    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                    "method": "item.get",
                    "params": {
                            "output": "extend",
                            "hostids": hosts_list,
                            "sortfield": "name"
                    },
                    "auth": authId,
                    "id": 1
                    }
            request = requests.post(path, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'content-type':'application/json-rpc'})
            request_res = request.json()['result']
            keys_list = []
            for items in request_res:
                    keys_list.append(items['key_'])
            keys_list = dict.fromkeys(keys_list).keys()
            data = {
                    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                    "method": "host.get",
                    "params": {
                            "filter":{
                                    "key_" : "vmware"
                            },
                            "output": "extend",
                    },
                    "auth": authId,
                    "id": 2
            }
            request = requests.post(path, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'content-type':'application/json-rpc'})
            request_res = request.json()['result']
            print request_res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) select item ids with key vmware

```
                "method": "item.get",
                "params": {
                        "output": ["itemid"],
                        "search":{
                                "key_" : "vmware"
                        }                            
                }
```

2.) then select hosts with these item ids

```
                "method": "host.get",
                "params": {
                        "output": "extend",
                        "itemids": [<itemsids from previous step>]                            
                },
```